23.10 on laptop don't know what happened, really slow not working
I have 23.10 installed on my laptop and recently installed some packages and now it is not working properly and unable to go past the login screen

Please describe your problem, currently the question is 'not working'. What errors do you get, what did you do to break the system ? What have you tried to fix it ?

Can you add more information? What packages did you install? and what is exactly not working means?

I turn my laptop on, go to login screen, I login and the screen goes black and freezes. The whole time since I turn on my laptop it just takes longer than expected.
